# Google Javascript Api Markers not visible

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to show markers along with my current location. In the below code location changes from default location to current location but the markers are not visible. Stores are retrieved correctly. I want to display the markers along with the my current location.

```
    function initMap() {

    //Set default location of google maps for demonstration purposes
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center :  {lat: 18.533333, lng: 73.866667},
        zoom: 10
    });

    //create global variables/objects 
    var pos = {};
    var strLoc = {};
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
    var request = {};

    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

            //Get current location to set the center of the google maps
            var pos = { 
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            //get your current location for finding places around you.
            //This should be a latlng object of google maps api.
            strLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(pos);


            //create a google maps request object
            request = {
                location: strLoc,
                radius: 500,
                types:['store']
            }


            //set current location on google maps based on HTML geolocation
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('You are Here');
            map.setCenter(pos);


            alert(request)
            var placeservice = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)
            placeservice.nearbySearch(request,callback)

        });


    }

}

function callback(places, status)
{

    if(status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
    {

        for(var i = 0; i<places.length; i++)
        {
            alert(places[i].name)
            createMarkers(places[i]);
        }
    }
}

function createMarkers(place)
{
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', function(){
      infoWindow.setContent(place.name);
      infoWindow.open(map,this);  
    })
}
```

Comment: Why do you say the stores are retrieved correctly? Why do you expect them to appear on the map?

Comment: I have put a alert(stores[i].name) in the call back function which displays the names of the stores.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  I don't see those (which would be really annoying if they worked) alerts.  I do see javascript errors: `Uncaught ReferenceError: storeRequest is not defined`, `InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama`, and `Uncaught ReferenceError: infoWindow is not defined`

Comment: I have edited the code which had some incorrect variables. I have put alert in for loop of callback function.

Comment: duplicate of [How to show markers on map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386609/how-to-show-markers-on-map)

Comment: duplicate of [Google Maps API, search autocomplete not zooming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825023/google-maps-api-search-autocomplete-not-zooming)

Answer (score 1):

I now get one javascript error: `InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama` on this line:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: place.geometry.location
});
```

Because at that point in your code `map` is a reference to the `<div>` with id="map", not the `google.maps.Map` object, which is local to the initMap function.  One option to fix your problem is to make it global.

```
var map; // global variable, outside of any function declarations
function initMap() {
  //default location
  // initialize global map variable.
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center :  {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044},
    zoom: 10
  });
// ...
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/54y84a6c/4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  //Set default location of google maps for demonstration purposes
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 18.533333,
      lng: 73.866667
    },
    zoom: 10
  });

  //create global variables/objects 
  var pos = {};
  var strLoc = {};
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map
  });
  var request = {};

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

      //Get current location to set the center of the google maps
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      //get your current location for finding places around you.
      //This should be a latlng object of google maps api.
      strLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(pos);


      //create a google maps request object
      request = {
        location: strLoc,
        radius: 500,
        types: ['store']
      }


      //set current location on google maps based on HTML geolocation
      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('You are Here');
      map.setCenter(pos);


      // alert(request)
      var placeservice = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)
      placeservice.nearbySearch(request, callback)

    });


  }

}

function callback(places, status) {

  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
      // alert(places[i].name)
      createMarkers(places[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarkers(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(place.name);
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```