# Google Maps Place Services

Tags: google-maps

How can I replace the lat + lng in this string with a variable from my code?

```
url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=parking&key=[YOUR KEY HERE]"
```

I'm trying to make nearby parking lots show up, but having no luck at all with making it work. Ironically, it did show them until I started editing the code to add my own custom markers. Any help would be appreciated.

I should note that I'm using geolocation which sets the lat lng as the following:

```
var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
```

Comment: related question: [Google Javascript Api Markers not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39442046/google-javascript-api-markers-not-visible)

Answer (score 0):

change location value in query string (API url)

```
<script>
var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        },

    url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+pos.lat+","+pos.lng+"&radius=1500&type=parking&key=[YOUR KEY HERE]";
</script>
```

Now use this `url` variable wherever you wants

Comment: Tried it but it just doesn't work. It's really frustrating. I've got:

Comment: Thanks @santosh. Tried it but it just doesn't work. It's really frustrating. I've got: Info Window code for geolocation permission, map code (including marker code & marker positions), create marker code, geolocation code, then this code: <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY API KEY]&callback=initMap">
 </script> . I tried to change this link to the places services link, but no luck.

Comment: @BarbaraDavis Any error ?? have you replaced `[MY API KEY]` to your actual key?

Comment: it's still not working, and I cannot believe you just asked me that. Of course I have my own key in that slot. :) Adding the "+pos.lat+" breaks the link

Comment: any error in console ?? send me the link of your project or post that on fiddle so i can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't have fiddle. My code was too long to send in here.